# XCode - set debugger on variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

is there a way to set the debugger on a set so that if the variable generates an error (e.g. an array being out of bounds), one is given the line number where this is happening?

I am looking specifically for instructions on how to do this in Xcode 3.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Out of curiosity any reason why your using xcode 3?

Comment: Work-related question, not personal. Who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a global "On Throw" exception breakpoint. If you open the break points window you should be able to add one, although I can't remember the exact steps in Xcode 3.

Once you have this turned on, the debugger will stop exactly where the exception is generated. This usually helps when an exception is being passed through a `performSelector` invocation and the stack trace is lost.